# Текст краткой новости без заголовков

Tags: php

Есть список новостей, в котором есть заголовок (Название новости) и краткий текст, который является сокращенным от полного. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы в краткую новость не выводилось содержание в тегах

`<h2 class="section-heading"></h2>`

`<blockquote></blockquote>`

И также

`<img class="img-responsive" src="img/картинка" alt=""></a><span class="caption text-muted"></span>`

Comment: Если вы получили свое решение - его следует оформить в виде ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал через `strip_tags(strip_tags_content($text))`, где

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
$tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
if($invert == FALSE) { 
return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
} 
else { 
return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
} 
} 
elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
} 
return $text; 
}
```

чтобы не было `<br>` после `<h2>`. Функция `strip_tags_content` удаляет содержимое тегов, а `strip_tags` убирает перенос строки.

Answer (score 0):

используйте `strip_tags`

```
<?php

$text = '<p>Параграф.</p><!-- Комментарий --> <a href="#fragment">Еще текст</a>';

echo strip_tags($text);

?>
```

[документы тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Почти то, что нужно, но (!) нужно сделать так, чтобы содержимое внутри вышеописанных тегов не выводилось вовсе

Comment: получается так, что текст внутри заголовка выводится обычным шрифтом. нужно, чтобы его вообще не было

Comment: @АндрейИванов покажите пример, что есть и что должно быть

Comment: http://f4.s.qip.ru/768CoNCR.png (краткая новость, в самом начале заголовок выводится)
http://f2.s.qip.ru/768CoNCS.png (полная - заголовок - <h2>)

Comment: @АндрейИванов вроде нормально работает функция. не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Перед тем как советовать функцию, желательно понимать, что она делает.

Comment: @Saidolim краткая новость (первый скрин) должна начинаться с `Consectetur adipiscing elit.`, а не с `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

Comment: Гляньте в описании функуции ниже : mariusz.tarnaski at wp dot pl ¶7 years ago
Hi. I made a function that removes the HTML tags along with their contents:

Comment: @splash58 более менее, только вот отступ для h2 в css срабатывает, получается что-то вроде http://f4.s.qip.ru/768CoNCT.png

Comment: определите для этого раздела другой стиль h2

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1.** Загружайте фрагмент в [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) или воспользуйтесь библиотекой [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (или [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/), [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) на выбор), затем рекурсивно обойдите ваш фрагмент и удаляйте ненужные теги;

Пример на simple_html_dom:

```
$html = str_get_html($html_text); 
foreach ($html->find('h2.section-heading, blockquote') as $element) {
    $element->outertext = '';
}
foreach ($html->find('img.img-resposive') as $element) {
    $parent = $element->parent();
    $next = $element->next_sibling();
    if ('A' === $parent->tag && 'caption text-muted' === $next->class) {
        $parent->outertext = '';
        $next->outertext = '';
    }
}
$short_text = $html->save();
```

**Вариант 2.** Напишите свой систаксический анализатор, который будет обрабатывать текстовый поток на предмет открытых и закрытых тегов и в ходе обработки удаляйте ненужное.

Вам может придти идея воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, но охватить всю задачу без возможных ложных срабатываний такое решение не позволит, поэтому не рекомендую.

Также учтите, что, по крайней мере, первый вариант может оказаться достаточно ресурсоемким на больших текстах, поэтому рекомендую кешировать результат.